# Json To Dto Class for map of String, String but same key allowed repeatedly

Tags: java, objectmapper

Requirement is in json, there will be map of string & string but multiple key having same value should be allowed.

Something like this

```
{
  "src": "A",
  "dest": "B",
  "interStoreType": {
    "C1": "C1",
    "C2": "C2",
    "C2": "C3",
    "C3": "C3"
  }
}
```

This value is in String in one db column, So, I use objectmapper to convert it to a Dto object.
By defult if I use map, it will be [C1:C1, C2:C3, C3:C3], it will take last value
So, tried with Multimap (guava), MultiValuedMap(apache commons collection), there also it is giving same value as of what Map gives.

Other ways are there like adding array in value part or join with delimeter.
But, I want to know the reason why object mapper is not creating multiple record for same key.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate keys? Whilst whether duplicate keys are permitted in JSON is up for debate, most libraries will have some logic to only use one. Are the keys actually duplicates, or the same key with a number appended?

Comment: number append is worst case, if first approach not works. Duplicate keys means in the example I provided, C2 is repeated twice

Comment: "most libraries will have some logic to only use one." oh this I was unaware of, if this is the case, better to follow some other approach. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't have duplicate keys in a map. A `MultiValuedMap` is a map of lists, so it is also a map, so it cannot have duplicate keys either.

Try to express your JSON like this:

```
{
  "src": "A",
  "dest": "B",
  "interStoreType": {
    "C1": ["C1"],
    "C2": ["C2","C3"],
    "C3": ["C3"]
  }
}
```